# mysql reformular consulta para que se usen los valores de resultado como columna

Tags: mysql

Buenas noches quisiera que me pudieran ayudar en mi problematica que se q es sencillo pero no la veo disculpen

tengo la siguiente consulta

```
SELECT mes, empresa, 
       sum(costo_vm) - sum(costo_promt) - sum(costo_desinc) AS util_n_p 
FROM ( SELECT MONTH(rptofactvm_base.fechaemision) AS mes, 
      rptofactvm_base.cliente AS empresa, rptofactvm_items.costo_prom * 
      rptofactvm_items.cantidad AS costo_promt, 
      rptofactvm_items.monto_desinc * rptofactvm_items.cantidad AS costo_desinc, 
      rptofactvm_items.neto AS costo_vm, rptofactvm_items.total_siniva AS venta_final 
FROM rptofactvm_items 
INNER JOIN rptofactvm_base ON rptofactvm_items.id_fact = rptofactvm_base.id 
ORDER BY empresa, mes) AS SUMA 
GROUP BY empresa, mes
```

me arroja el siguiente resultado:

```
+-----+----------------------+-------------+
| mes | empresa              | util_n_p    |
+-----+----------------------+-------------+
|  10 | empresa 1            |  1998375.38 |
|  11 | empresa 1            | 12852093.88 |
|  10 |empresa 2             |  6273978.73 |
|  11 | empresa 2            | 45828889.13 |
|  10 | empresa 3            | NULL        |
|  11 | empresa 3            | 11486653.27 |
|  10 | empresa 4            |  9855668.74 |
|  11 | empresa 4            | 37165981.79 |
+-----+----------------------+-------------+
```

mi consulta me da los datos que quiero pero necesito formatearlos de la siguiente manera

```
+-----+----------------------+-------------+
| mes | empresa 1            | empresa 2   |
+-----+----------------------+-------------+
|  10 | 1998375.38           |  6273978.73 |
|  11 | 12852093.88          | 45828889.13 |
+-----+----------------------+-------------+
```

como puedo reformular mi consulta

Comment: Podrias pasarnos las tablas al menos con datos ficticios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para responder tú respuesta más específicamente necesitaría la estructura de tus tablas, pero de una manera general podría ser algo así:

Cabe mencionar que solo funciona para un número fijo de empresas, si deseas agregar más empresas tendrás que agregar más condicionantes:

Primero creamos la tabla con tu información:

```
CREATE TABLE empresas (
  id_empresa int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  empresa varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE indicadores (
  id_empresa int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  mes int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  util_n_p double(11,2) DEFAULT NULL
);
INSERT INTO empresas (id_empresa,empresa) VALUES (1, 'empresa 1'),(2, 'empresa 2'),(3, 'empresa 3'),(4, 'empresa 4');
INSERT INTO indicadores (id_empresa,mes,util_n_p) VALUES (1, 10, 1998375.38),(1, 11, 12852093.88),(2, 10, 6273978.73),(2, 11, 45828889.13),(3, 10, NULL),(3, 11, 11486653.27),(4, 10, 9855668.74),(4, 11, 37165981.79);
```

Y después para la consulta usaremos la sentencia CASE para cada una de las empresas y al final agrupamos por mes:

```
SELECT
indicadores.mes,
SUM(CASE WHEN empresas.id_empresa = 1 THEN indicadores.util_n_p ELSE 0 END) 'Empresa 1',
SUM(CASE WHEN empresas.id_empresa = 2 THEN indicadores.util_n_p ELSE 0 END) 'Empresa 2',
SUM(CASE WHEN empresas.id_empresa = 3 THEN indicadores.util_n_p ELSE 0 END) 'Empresa 3',
SUM(CASE WHEN empresas.id_empresa = 4 THEN indicadores.util_n_p ELSE 0 END) 'Empresa 4',
GROUP_CONCAT(empresas.id_empresa)
FROM
empresas
INNER JOIN indicadores ON empresas.id_empresa = indicadores.id_empresa
GROUP BY mes
```

Al final quedaria algo asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te dejo el ejercicio completo en: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e695fb1d0bee016c00e71b6ccd220524